# Passing variables in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a very complicated windows application which has 8 forms. There are "Previous" and "Next" buttons on each form to back and forth for easily editing forms.

```
 private void ShowNext()
    {
        if (FormNext == null)
            FormNext = new SomeForm(this);
        FormNext.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void ShowPrev()
    {
        FormPrev.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowNext();
    }

    private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowPrev();
    }
```

Each form will execute different sql insert table command. But the question is that I don't want to finish all insertion on each form.

What I want to is to finish all in the last form once the user confirms the correct input values.
That means I have to pass all variables from the very beginning to the last one.

Question: can the memory hold all variables? How to pass them cross forms?

Thanks.

Comment: 8 forms doesn't sound very complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a static public field in your main form, and update the value in each sub forms. Finally select the field in your last form for insertion

Something on the following lines:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form //your main fomr
    {
        public static List<MyContainerClass> myContainer= new List<MyContainerClass>();
        .............
```

Here MyContainerClass could be some class defined in your code, which can hold all the values you want to persist. If its just a string, then you may create a list of string. Then in each form set value

```
Form1.myContainer.Add(new_values);
```

In the last form you can access the values

```
foreach(MyContainerClass mc in Form1.myContainer)
{
//Do your work
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your string queries easily to your new/old form's public variable like below

```
protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyForm2 x = new MyForm2();
    x.Query = "My Query";   // here "Query" is your custom public string variable on form2
    x.Show()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a static singleton class that will hold all your variables.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to hold a reference to some context that has access to the data you need.

```
protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SomeContext.Push(myFormStateDataThatIsReady);
    ShowNext();
}
```

Then, when the final step comes around, you can pull this data off that context and write that data.

Comment: It is interesting. But I don't know what is the Push method in windows form?

Comment: It's a method on the `SomeContext` class, which doesnt exist. The above code is only an example. You would need to implement some kind of storage mechanism to access on your forms.